# Is this endgame a draw (hacked - TestViking)?

Tags: endgame, pawns, draw, kings

[In my recent online blitz video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWj-toK88mA), I got the following endgame with the black pieces. With white to move, the game went as follows

```
[White "hacked"]
[Black "TestViking"]
[FEN "8/3k2p1/1p1P1pP1/p1p5/P1P1PK2/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.e5 Ke6 2.exf6 Kxf6 3.d7 Ke7 1/2-1/2
```

...white offered draw and I agreed. Was the position a draw or did one of the sides have a win or winning chances?

Comment: What did the engine say?

Comment: @Rafiek StockFish DD says it is equal after 1.e5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was drawn all along. 1...Ke6! was the only move for black to draw since he cannot allow white to force ...gxf6, nor allow the white king up to support the d-pawn. After 4.Ke5 Kxd7 5.Kd5 there's no way for either side to make progress as the kings will just be shuffled between d5/e5 and d7/e7. There is one practical chance/trap that might be worth trying before agreeing to a draw; black can play 5...Kc7 and see if white goes for 6.Ke6, in which case black wins with 6...b5!, forcing the creation of a passed pawn and queening first. As long as white spots this and plays 6.Ke5 instead there's nothing more to do, though.

Edit: I realized black cannot play Ke7 at the end as it loses to Kc6. However, Kc7 still draws as before due to white being unable to play Ke6.